# How to transition a view (i.e List) to appear from a certain point on the screen in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a list that occupies 60% of the top of the screen. I want the list to animate by sliding in from the bottom of that 60% during the transition instead of the bottom of the phone screen. If you take a look at my code, you will get an idea on what im talking about...

```
struct ContentView: View {
    let controls = ["backward.fill", "play.fill", "forward.fill"]
    
    @State private var showingList = false
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            VStack {
                Group {
                    if showingList {
                        List(0..<50) {
                            Text("\($0)")
                        }
                        .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                                                
                    } else {
                        Spacer()
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.6)
//I want the list to slide in from the bottom of the top frame that takes 60% of the height.
                
                HStack {
                    ForEach(controls, id: \.self) {
                        Image(systemName: $0)
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.4)
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation {
                        showingList.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
//I don't want the view to slide in from the bottom of the phone right here
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the list to be hidden behind your controls while it appears. You can try adding a background behind the controls:

```
            HStack {
                ForEach(controls, id: \.self) {
                    Image(systemName: $0)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: geo.size.width, maxHeight: geo.size.height * 0.4)
            .background(Color(uiColor: .systemBackground)) // <- add a background here to hide the list during transition
            .onTapGesture {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 4)) {
                    showingList.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
```